# Compare enum values to strings java

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

I have an enum `CommandType` that lists 23 types:

`HELP, ROLE, TIMEOUT, REMINDME, CHANGELOG, SERVERINFO, STATS,...`

But I need to convert them to strings later in the code. Right now my method looks like this:

```
case "CHANGELOG":
        return CommandType.CHANGELOG;
    case "HELP":
        return CommandType.HELP;
    case "LOGHISTORY":
        return CommandType.LOGHISTORY;
    case "LOGJOINS":
        return CommandType.LOGJOINS;
    case "PAUSE":
        return CommandType.PAUSE;
    case "REMINDME":
        return CommandType.REMINDME;
    case "ROLE":
        return CommandType.ROLE;
```

et cetera. Is there an easier/cleaner way of doing this? I have considered setting the enum values equal to strings, but the same method would have to happen somewhere.

Comment: If the names match for all values, you can use `CommandType.valueOf("CHANGELOG")` etc.  The `case` statement can be removed if there is no other logic other than mapping the String value to enum.

Comment: This isn't the same as the Question marked as duplicate. The heading is similarly worded, but this question asks for more general String -> Enum conversion